# Iphone 6s plus not able to side load

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My iphone 6s plus is not even being recognized by Xcode. It says Iphone unavailable. I have looked at build settings and checked ios deployment target to make sure it matches mine. It says 9.0 and mine is 9.2. But it should still work. It does not. I have followed a few other answers on here with green checks but none seem to work for me. I have turned rebooted my iphone. reset my computer and added a team and clicked fix. but none of that seems to work. I have clicked a link that tells you to Product -> Destination -> myDevice (which is an ineligible list item). But it wont work. If anyone can help please do

Comment: please share the xcode version you are using. you need xcode 7.2 for device running on 9.2

Comment: I fear you need xcode 7.2 installed.

Comment: @RatulSharker it's being installed as I type. I'll let you know if this works

Comment: @RatulSharker still doesn't work now it says generic ios device. instead of my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing XCode 7.2 will resolve your problem.

Comment: It means that your device is not discovered yet by XCode.
You can read more about generic iOS Device from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287929/what-is-generic-ios-device-in-xcode-7-1-run-destinations-list