# Xcode- no devices registered in your account- Work around?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am a new Apple Developer, I am looking to explore Metal API, not developing for iPhones or iPad, at this moment. I am building basic triangles right now, working with iOS Generic Device.

I have been facing this bug while trying to build-

> Failed to create provisioning profile.
>   There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

and the other is-

> Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.anuragazad.MBE-2-1'

Now, I have signed into one of my Apple IDs, going by the errors, it seems the IDE wants me to plugin my iPhone or iPad and register it, I do not want to do that. Is there a work around for this? I just want to explore Metal and use Build for Generic iOS devices.

PS. Please bear with any incorrect usage I might have had in the question, very new to graphics/metal/xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metal apps **do not run** on the `iOS` simulator; they require a device with an Apple A7 chip or later. Apps created for `macOS/OS X` will of course run on `macOS`.

> Apple Staff Reply: Metal is not supported in the iOS Simulator.

↳ https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31120

Comment: @I'L'l
So, I am trying to run-
https://github.com/metal-by-example/sample-code/tree/master/objc/02-ClearScreen/ClearScreen

Issue- Metal is not supported by iOS and UIKit is not supported by MacOS, so if I choose generic iOS Device then it builds, macOS fails as it cant find UIKit and iOS fails because metal is not supported, could you guide me what should the appropriate settings be to run the code in the link ?
Will really appreciate help I have been trying to get this to run for few hours now

Comment: It will build yes as that's the purpose of using a "Generic Device", although `iOS` apps do not run on `macOS` unless using the simulator, and as mentioned `Metal` does not run in the simulator. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287929/what-is-generic-ios-device-in-xcode-7-1-run-destinations-list, as it explains what a "Generic Device" is all about.

Comment: THANK YOU!
I understand it now, initially I did connect my iPhone but there was a mismatch in the target OS version that I chose which was causing the issue
A lot of time wasted but atleast now I am very much familiar with how the project configurations work on xcode, probably the best way to learn, facing bugs!